# GeoPandas exporting to shape slowly

Tags: python, gdal, geopandas

I'm using GeoPandas and GDAL to convert a raster file to a polygon SHP.
To convert to SHP, I use the GDAL Polygonize function. This conversion creates a 200MB SHP and takes about 1.5min which is acceptable.

The raster file contains indexes. It's a number corresponding to the antenna with the most power at this location. In the shapefile, the polygons must also take the corresponding antenna code which is a string.
As I didn't find any solution to put this string value before using the polygonize function, I then open the shapefile with GeoPandas, add the new column, and export the file with the `gdf.to_file`. The problem with this is that it takes more than 5min to export the file. I don't really understand how it can be faster to vectorize and export the layer than just exporting a layer with GeoPandas.

Here is the code I use:

```py
        gdf = gpd.read_file(output_file)

        csv_file = filename + ".csv"
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        idx = df['idx'].to_list()
        conditions = [gdf['idx'] == n for n in idx]
        choices = df['netid'].to_list()
        gdf['value'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
        gdf.to_file(output_file)
```

Is there a way to speed up the process?

Comment: Install `pyogrio` and use it as an engine. `gdf.to_file(output_file, engine="pyogrio")`

Comment: maybe the conversion to vector is not the right way to go. There are various tools to analyze raster data and they are super fast, maybe they fit better for your use case

Comment: The pyogrio helps a little bit, I'm 1 min faster but it's still slow. If someone has another alternative to be even faster, it would be nice, otherwise I will go this way